# C# Correctly parsing an XElement's Attributes into a list (exception help)

Tags: c#, xml, linq

Good day everyone, i hope you are all happy and healthy :)

My problem is as follows:

I begin by bringing in my main enumerable with a bunch of XElement's (waypoints) in:

IEnumerable waypoints = file.Descendants("Waypoints").First().Elements();

I then begin iterating through them as follows:

```
foreach (XElement el in waypoints)
        {
            try
            {
                //ok so this should be one element here..
                Waypoint tempWP =
                    new Waypoint((el.Attribute("X") != null ? Convert.ToSingle(el.Attribute("X").Value) : 0.0F),
                                 (el.Attribute("Y") != null ? Convert.ToSingle(el.Attribute("Y").Value) : 0.0F),
                                 (el.Attribute("Z") != null ? Convert.ToSingle(el.Attribute("Z").Value) : 0.0F),
                                 (el.Attribute("Zone") != null ? Convert.ToUInt64(el.Attribute("Zone").Value) : 0),
                                 (el.Attribute("Type") != null ? el.Attribute("Type").Value : ""),
                                 (el.Attribute("SafeRadius") != null ? Convert.ToUInt32("SafeRadius") : 0),
                                 (el.Attribute("Guid") != null ? Convert.ToUInt64("Guid") : 0));
                ret.Add(tempWP);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

            }
        }
```

From my debugging, I know that el = Waypoint X="1032.91858" Y="-3671.47949" Z="35.0046425" Zone="111" Type="none" SafeRadius="1" Guid="111" /

So the XElement is coming in fine. As you can see, I am attempting to convert the X/Y/Z into singles, Zone into a UInt64.. and others, and then I wish to add them to the returning waypoint list.

However, every time my foreach runs, it hits an exception... "Input string was not in a correct format.". Does anyone have an idea why this might be occuring? I believe that my null checks and conversions should be correct, no?

Thank you very much for helping out. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the values you are trying to convert to numeric types is either an empty string or contains letters.

Comment: My null checks should take care of that and input a default value if the type is empty/has letters?

Comment: Also as i posted above, that was the exact XElement that caused the exception.. as you can see each value should work correctly, no?

Comment: Ok i'm stupid, i forgot to add "el.Attribute" to the bottom two values. Thanks anyways ryudice.